# How to quickly find the main() in java project using eclipse ?

Tags: java, eclipse

In a case I have the src folder of project with a lot of classes in it  , how could I detect which is the class with the `main()` that the project running start with  ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- open the project you want to run class from;
- in main window: Run -> Open Run Dialog...(Run Configurations);
- in the left section open the project type your project belongs to (if it's main function it would be "Java Application" in your case);
- under this category your should see all the "executable" class names;

Comment: For me, this fails - the third step shows only classes that I've run previously.

Answer (score 9):

From the Eclipse IDE menu, select *Search>Java ...* .

In the dialog, enter:

- "main" as the search string.
- "Method" in the "Search For" box.
- "Declarations" in the "Limit to" box.

This gives you a convenient, hierarchical list in the "Search" view linking to all the classes with main() methods.

Click on one of these to navigate to the class. Then right-click *Run As* or *Debug As* to run.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that in a jar, *you are not limited to one `main()` method*. There can be several `main()s` scattered across different classes, in "production" sources as well as in "test" sources etc.

If you know for sure that the jar built from this project can be launched using `java -jar the.jar`, then it means the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` has a `Main-Class` entry: you should look in there for the class name.

Otherwise, you have to search for methods named `main` with a classical find tool... (see @AndyThomas' answer)

Answer (score 2):

If there is a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file, you can search for `Main-Class` in it.

Comment: Sadly, that's not the case when having more than 1 class with `public static void main(String[] args)` method and even worse if the project doesn't have a *MANIFEST.MF* file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Run -> Run Configurations (Alt + R + N)
```

or

```
Run -> Debug Configurations (Alt + R + B)
```

[image: Example of debug configuration]

Answer (score 1):

> Your_Eclipse_Project -> Export... -> Runnable Jar File...

here the top section of the dialog should list down all the classes having `main()` method, something like below

[image]

Alternatively,

> Your_Eclipse_Project -> Run As... -> Java Application

will launch a dialog, which lists down all the main types which can be selected and run. This will search through all the jars referenced by your projects too.